# display annotation for zero value in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I am creating a column chart using google charts API. I created all data columns and displayed annotations in the column. But the problem is, if column value is zero then annotation is not displaying. How to resolve this problem. I need to display '0'.

my code is:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart4);
        function drawChart4() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn({ type: 'string', lable:'Something'});
        data.addColumn('number','SLA Met');
        data.addColumn({ type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
        data.addColumn('number','SLA Not Met'); 
        data.addColumn({ type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
        data.addRows([
          ['Ancillary',<%=ANCILLARY_MET %>,<%=ANCILLARY_MET %>,<%=ANCILLARY_NOTMET%>,<%=ANCILLARY_NOTMET%> ],
          ['CIS',<%=CIS_MET %>,<%=CIS_MET %>,<%=CIS_NOTMET%>,<%=CIS_NOTMET%>],
          ['ERP FSCM',<%=FSCM_MET %>,<%=FSCM_MET %>,<%=FSCM_NOTMET%>,<%=FSCM_NOTMET%>],
          ['ERP HCM',<%=HCM_MET %>,<%=HCM_MET %>,<%=HCM_NOTMET%>,<%=HCM_NOTMET%>]
          ]);

          var options = {'colors' : ['#3366CC', '#fcb441'],
                  title: 'Resolution SLA(Tower Wise)',titleTextStyle:{fontName:'"Arial"'},
                 hAxis: {title: 'Tower', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black',fontSize:'15',fontName:'"Arial"'}},
                 vAxis: {minValue:0},
                 legend:{position: 'bottom'},
                 tooltip:{trigger:'none'}
                };
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('g5'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using wrong type `number` for annotation. For

```
{ type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}
```

and input as strings, annotation is shown even for value '0'.

See also [docs annotation role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole)

**Update:** To clarify, you have to change only input type for annotation, for example from

```
['Ancillary', 15, 15, 3, 3 ],
```

to

```
['Ancillary', 15, '15', 3, '3' ]
```

So your code would be:

```
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', lable:'Something'});
    data.addColumn('number','SLA Met');
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn('number','SLA Not Met'); 
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i am unable to get solution.If I change annotation type chart is not displaying.

Comment: You have to change also your input values. For example from 0 to '0' or from 350 to '350'.

Comment: "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string" error on chart.data.addRows([
['Ancillary','0','0','10','10' ]]);

Comment: One thing that may make the annotation not appear, is if the value of 'the point' is null, changing from null to zero, solves the problem. It happend to me in a column chart.